# Java in MATLAB_R2016b

Tags: java, matlab, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use Java in current MATLAB Version (R2016b).

I just have this simple Class with no dependencies:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

I changed my JVM for Matlab to my local one as described [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103056-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using-for-mac-os)

and with `version -java` I get following output:

```
Java 1.8.0_111-b14 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

My Java class was compiled by IntelliJ with Project SDK 1.8.0_111 and the containing folder of my `.class` files were added with `javaaddpath` to the MATLAB dynamic class paths.

I have no more ideas what could be wrong.

Using older SDKs is not possible as you can not download Java 6 or 7 anymore. (It seems you need a long term support account from oracle to do this)

Anyone can help me getting this to work?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the [static path](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/static-java-classpath-hacks) instead?

Comment: Yes I also tried modifying the static path with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried packaging my IntelliJ project into a jar file as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/packaging-a-module-into-a-jar-file.html).

Now adding the path with `javaaddpath /my/path/to/project.jar` to the dynamic classpath seems to work as I can use my Java classes with their full package identifier like `com.example.Main` in MATLAB now.

Kinda frustrating that `.class` files won't work with same project settings in IntelliJ.

Comment: Adding individual `.class` files should work as well - there must have been some other problem with it. Though using jars is a much better way anyway.